# Mass unsubscribes

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, unsubscriber

I have a list of 173 email addresses that have previously unsubscribed from our marketing messages from another marketing automation software.  Is there a way to update their subscription statuses to `unsubscribe` without having to go to their individual profile and checking the box for each one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Follow these steps:

1. Create a CSV with their Status, SubscriberKy and EmaiAddress
2. Populate the status as for each contact as "Unsubscribed"
3. Import this into the All Subscriber's List

Note: If you are using an Enterprise2.0 account, this has to be done at the Parent Business Unit.

Result: All 173 should have their statuses and the All Subscribers List changed to "Unsubscribe" and will be suppressed at send time.

If subscribers exist in MC and have SusbcriberKeys assigned to them, then you can go this route, as the duplicated email addresses wont matter. the system will look at their sub keys and match the emails. If the contacts are not in MC and you want to ensure that they can never be contacted, you can add the emails to an Auto Suppression List.

Reference:

- [Auto Suppression of contacts](https://dare2mull.wordpress.com/2017/06/13/salesforce-marketing-cloud-exacttarget-auto-suppression-of-contacts/)

Comment: Thanks - If an email address is already in MC (there may be a couple of duplicates) would it just do an update vs an add?

Comment: If subscribers exist in MC and have SusbcriberKeys assigned to them, then you can go this route, as the duplicated email addresses wont matter. the system will look at their sub keys and match the emails. If the contacts are not in MC and you want to ensure that they can never be contacted, you can add the emails to an Auto Suppression List.